# how do I custom add an element in wordpress elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am making a website on wordpress with the help of elementor and I want to add some custom element and some image to a elementor widget. I am using the realhomes theme.

This is how [my site](https://godrejurbanparkmumbai.com/) looks like

This is the following element I want to edit

[image]

I want to add an image and some text in this element but I cant seem to do it via elementor because the only options i get in elementor are

[image]

I was hoping to edit it in the source file but could find it, can some1 help me out here!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can follow 2 different ways to solve this issue.

**Way 1:**
As you said, you need to add an image and some text. So, you can use the image box widget from the elemntor in the same row or column wherever you want.

**Way 2.**
Register a new widget (To create a new widget this article will help you https://github.com/elementor/elementor-hello-world)

Thank you